# Do I have more thn one wireless driver modules?

Tags: wifi, drivers, kernel-modules

```
$ lsmod | grep iwl
iwldvm                232283  0 
mac80211              652718  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               179412  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              494362  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
```

I heard that iwlwifi is the module of my wireless driver. What is `iwldvm`? Why does it use `iwlwifi`? After I unload `iwldvm`, my wireless adpter can't scan available wireless networks.

Why is `mac80211` loaded, given that my laptop is not mac?

Is there something with the modules already loaded or not yet loaded, which may potentially cause wireless connection problem?

My OS is 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad T400, and wireless controller/adapter is

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-34-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.1.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:49 memory:f4200000-f4201fff
```

Answer (score 1):

`mac` here doesn't have any relation to Macs: *MAC* stands for [Media Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_access_control). The module described in details [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/mac80211) and it just provides a framework for Wi-Fi drivers to build upon.

Also, [cfg80211](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/cfg80211) provides the configuration layer. As I understand it, `iwldvm` just provides lower-level functionality for `iwlwifi` (thus the dependency) and other Intel WLAN device drivers.

For the record, I have a Intel 1030 wireless and this is what I have (looks similar to what you have):

```
$ lsmod|grep iwl
iwldvm                184887  0 
mac80211              648753  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               169263  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              476584  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
```

Comment: Thanks. Are my wireless driver modules just the four modules listed?

Comment: @Tim Judging from my machine (which has a Intel wireless card, too) I think that yes.

Comment: According to your reply, is it correct that the modules are build on one another in the following levels from low to high: mac80211 -> iwldvm -> iwlwifi -> cfg80211?
But the "used by" relation between the modules shown by `lsmod` indicates: cfg80211 -> mac80211, iwlwifi -> iwldvm?